# File path null for uploaded video

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, filepath

My app allow user to upload video from device and then i am trying to get the file extension of uploaded video.It works fine on my device but I am getting below exception on fabric for some users.I failed to understand why `yourRealPath` is becoming null.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)' on
>   a null object reference

```
private void uploadVideo() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
           String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedVideoUri);
           String fileExtn = yourRealPath.substring(yourRealPath.lastIndexOf("."));
       }
   }
}

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     */
    private String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) { if (id.startsWith("raw:")) { return id.replaceFirst("raw:", ""); }}
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

//            // Return the remote address
//            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
//                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }
//    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
//        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
//    }
    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri.
     */
    private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                 String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    private boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    private boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    private boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

As per pskink comment-

```
06-26 12:48:53.800 31654-31654/xyz I/System.out:
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@c03ff32
    0 {
       _id=578
       _data=/storage/emulated/0/Movies/cut_video2.mp4
       _display_name=cut_video2.mp4
       _size=6721597
       mime_type=video/mp4
       date_added=1525085212
       date_modified=1525067238
       title=cut_video2
       duration=30000
       artist=<unknown>
       album=Movies
       resolution=1920x1080
       description=null
       isprivate=null
       tags=null
       category=null
       language=null
       mini_thumb_data=null
       latitude=null
       longitude=null
       datetaken=1525067238000
       mini_thumb_magic=6883263867472584903
       bucket_id=-1730634595 06-26 12:48:53.805 31654-31654/xyzI/System.out:   bucket_display_name=Movies
       bookmark=null
       width=1920
       height=1080
       resumePos=0
       isPlayed=0
       addr=null
       langagecode=null
       is_secretbox=0
       weather_ID=0
       is_360_video=0
       recordingtype=-1
       recording_mode=0
       type3dvideo=<unknown>
       is_drm=0
       is_favorite=0
       video_view_mode=-1
       video_codec_info=MPEG4
       audio_codec_info=MP3
    }
    <<<<<
```

Comment: you have `selectedVideoUri` - use it in `ContnetResolver#query()` method and call `DataBaseUtils#dumpCursor()`, what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: @pskink posted in question

Comment: @pskink i am not getting any exception in my device..but i see in crashlytics that other users get

Comment: so if you have `mime_type=video/mp4` then by calling `ContentResolver#getType` you will get it in two lines of code instead of your dozens of lines of not working code

Comment: @pskink but my app support other video formats  also besides mp4..and i also need file path in my app

Comment: no, you dont need a file path, what for?

Comment: @pskink file path i need for other functionalities in my app..its video editing app.

Comment: see https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html, start reading from: `"What Not To Do"`

Comment: @pskink read that..what am i doing wrong in above code? i am checking scheme and based on that using uri..if scheme is file then calling getPath and not using MediaStore for contentUri

Comment: you are doing exactly the same what is described in **"What Not To Do"** section - instead you should really do what is inside **"What To Do"** section as this is the only supported option

Comment: @pskink I am neither "Just Grabing the Path" nor I am "using MediaStore in content uri".plz explain